# Nelmio API Doc Array Parameter

Tags: symfony, swagger, symfony4, nelmioapidocbundle

In terms of Symfony 4, using `Swagger\Annotations`, how may I define a query `Parameter` as an Array?

```
q[a]=1&q[b]=foo
```

I was doing it using Symfony 2 few years ago and cannot recall it nor find in Google... Please advice

Comment: Should it be query or body parameter? Should `a` and `b` keys also be provided?

Comment: a query with a keys, yes